# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_member' error while trying to find if user is in a specific server discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.guild:
        userid = message.author.id
        guild = client.get_guild(123456789) #example id
        if guild.get_user(userid) is not None:
            pass
        else:
            await message.channel.send("You aren't in example server")
```

This is meant to check if the message is in a DM, and if it is, it checks if they are in a specified server. When I run this, I get "NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_user'"

Comment: Have you enabled intents?

Comment: Yes, intents are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `guild.get_member(userid)`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.guild:
        userid = message.author.id
        guild = client.get_guild(123456789) #example id
        if guild.get_member(userid) is not None:
            pass
        else:
            await message.channel.send("You aren't in example server")
```

Comment: I've tried this as well, I still get the same error.

Comment: @temp84323 then you're not copying the ID of the guild correctly, which is causing the guild to become `None`